# SQL - SSRS Search for list of values using LIKE

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

First I will show you example data, expected input and output:

```
VALUE1 | QTY
-------------
111-01 | 5
111-02 | 3
111-03 | 2
112-01 | 4
```

Expected input from user is VALUE1 or list of VALUE1 ( in SSRS multiple value, variable TEXT).
Expected output is for example SUM of QTY for each VALUE1 selected by user, but with this condition

```
like SUBSTRING(VALUE1,1,3)+'%'
```

In this case for user selection 111-01 output is

```
VALUE1 | QTY
-------------
111    | 10
```

So far it seems like LIKE operator in IN statement. I have found only solution which is to split the parameter from SSRS and do some loop as (pseudocode)

```
foreach @parameter in @parameter.Split
where VALUE1 like '@parameter[0]'+'%' or ...
```

I think there is some more elegant solution. Anyway, this solution is really slow. I am not much experienced with SSRS so maybe some grouping after dataset is created can be solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you might want to try:

1. pseudocode:

   > ```
   > WITH    condition
   >       AS ( SELECT   SUBSTRING(c.SplitValue, 1, 3) Criteria
   >            FROM     dbo.fncSplit('111-1,112-2,113-3,114-4,115-1,116-1', ',') c
   >          )
   > SELECT  SUM(t.QTY)
   > FROM dbo.tblTest t
   > INNER JOIN condition con ON con.Criteria = SUBSTRING(t.Value1, 1, 3)
   > ```
2. try to do a full text index on the table and the performance might be improved